# Msbuild copy and flatten with unique file names

Tags: c#, msbuild, build-process, mstest

I'm trying to copy **multiple** files from a deep source tree that have **the same file name**. For example TestResults.trx. I want to copy them into a **single directory (i.e. flattened)**. Problem is they just overwrite each other and I just end up with a single  TestResults.trx in the directory.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SilverlightTestResults Include=".\**\*.trx" Exclude=".\TestResults\*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(SilverlightTestResults)" DestinationFolder=".\TestResults">
```

I thought I could do a transform using some [well known metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313%28VS.80%29.aspx) but there doesn't seem to be anything unique in there to do it (the test results I'm trying to copy live in directories like this: .\SomeProject\bin\debug\TestResults.trx).

Copying to a directory like this like this would be ideal:

```
.\TestResults\TestResults1.trx
.\TestResults\TestResults2.trx
.\TestResults\TestResults3.trx
```

I don't care about the actual names as long as they are unique.

Any ideas, looks like a custom task is required?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to flatten the structure in the first place?

Comment: These files will be picked up by Cruise Control and merged into the build log. Cruise control doesn't have great support for wildcards. For example, in ccnet.config you can do this: TestResults\\*.trx, but not this  TestResults\\**\\*.trx. Additionally I could have my build script generate unique file names but would have to override targets from the Silverlight toolkit, if changes can be isolated to the build script its a nice win.

Comment: I also had a look at xcopy to see if I could just shell out to that, but doesn't look like it supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide a solution that just uses msbuild - you could either use [msbuildtasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) 
to use the **<Add />** task for incrementing a counter.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
    <FileCounter>0</FileCounter>
</PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles SilverlightTestResults Include=".\**\*.trx" Exclude=".\TestResults\*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Math.Add Numbers="$(FileCounter);1">
        <Output TaskParameter="FileCounter" PropertyName="FileCounter" />
    </Math.Add>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'.\TestResults\%(Filename)_$(FileCounter)%(Extension)')"
    />
</Target>
```

However you might do better with a custom task or probably executing a powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a custom task will be required.

You could look to see what functionality the `Move` task from the community task project ([link here](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)) offers, but if it doesn't do what you want then it is open source, so it will be trivial to check the source and modify it to suit your needs.